# codestrong app uses backbone methods (on, off, trigger)

Tags: backbone.js, controller, titanium, titanium-alloy

SDK 3.2.1

I'm studing CodeStrong-2012 app and I've noticed undocumented methods applied to controllers objects (on, off, trigger).
Later, I've found this ChangeLog for alloy:

> 1.0.0 (19 February 2013)
>   ** Breaking Changes **
>
> Backbone Events API Removed from View Proxies and Controllers
>   For Alloy View proxies and Controllers, that is, objects either referenced with $.myid 
>   or created with createController and getView methods, you cannot use the Backbone Events
>   API on, off and trigger methods to bind and unbind event callbacks, or fire events. Use the 
>   Titanium SDK API addEventListener, removeEventListener and fireEvent methods instead.
>
> Previously, Alloy View proxies and Controllers could use the Backbone Events API.

Problem is, if I change that in code, for instance, changing the line:

```
 //oldSection is a controller created with Alloy.createController
oldSection.off('nav', sectionNav);
```

to

```
oldSection.removeEventListener('nav', sectionNav);
```

I get the error:

```
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at alloy/controllers/main.js:24: Uncaugh
t TypeError: Object #<Controller> has no method 'removeEventListener'
```

**Am I doing something wrong?
Should I keep using Backbone methods on, off, trigger?**

Answer (score 0):

You can't add and remove event listener to controller object. However, you can do that on view object:

```
var view = oldSection.getView();
view.removeEventListener('nav', sectionNav);
```

[Alloy.Controller](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Alloy.Controller) has just few methods without `on/off` or `add/removeEventListener`.

Comment: Hi Daniula, So, if I understood, the Alloy changelog refers to view objects (that before were able to use backbone events). Then the methods on, off, trigger still applies to controllers, right?

Comment: I've just edit my answer with link to Alloy.Controller documentation. There is no way to listen and fire event on this object. You have to use any view element to do that.

Comment: There are no methods listed because the on/off/trigger methods are Backbone methods, not Alloy. In fact, Alloy.Controller inherits from Backbone.Events. I've compiled codestrong against SDK3.2.1 and  I can assure you that on/off/trigger works great.

Comment: Looks like this is another un/semi-documented feature in Alloy :)

Comment: I've learned more from codeStrong App than from Titanium Documentation, sad to say that! Those on/off/trigger events are used there to pass messages thru custom events between controllers...

Answer (score 0):

Here it is the only part of Appcelerator documentation I could find that actually talks about those on, off, trigger events:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Collection_and_Model_Objects

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Collection_and_Model_Objects

take a look at the end.

Answer (score 0):

For new readers, a great Titanium Titan / dev, Fokke Zandbergen, posted this article which contradicts the above comments.  http://www.tidev.io/2014/09/10/the-case-against-ti-app-fireevent-2/

From the post:
"Did you known that every Alloy controller is an event dispatcher? It extends Backbone.Events enabling you to use $.trigger() and ctrl.on(). If you don’t use Alloy, you can of course still extend Backbone’s Event dispatcher like we do in the last examle or create your own.

These JS-only events don’t cross the bridge and Backbone throws in some nice extras like ctrl.off() which can even remove all listeners to (a certain event of) the object.

BackBone 1.x has even more event-related goodness like once() and listenTo() but at the moment Alloy still ships with 0.9.2."

foo.js:

```
var bar = Alloy.createController('bar');

bar.on('logOut', function onLogOut(e) {

    // so bar doesn't keep us from GC
    bar.off('logOut', onLogOut);

    // so we don't keep bar from GC
    bar = null;
});
```

bar.js:

```
function onLogOutButtonClick(e) {
    $.trigger('logOut');

    // we can also free ourself from listeners
    // $.off();
}
```

I just tested this and it works as expected!
- Ti SDK: 3.3.0.GA
- iPad 7.1 Simulator